# How does one use numpy's Meshgrid function with a random interval rather than a equally spaced one?

Tags: python, numpy, random, plot

Conceptually this is sort of what I wanted to do. I wanted to select random points in a 2D plane and then plot a surface plot of how that would look like. Similarly, an alternative (sub-optimal idea) could be to grade a Meshgrid and select N random points and their corresponding heights and then plot them in a surface plot.

Currently the only successful way that I've been able to make surface plots is with equally intervaled points using the following:

```
start_val, end_val = -1,1
N = 100
x_range = np.linspace(start_val, end_val, N)
y_range = np.linspace(start_val, end_val, N)
(X,Y) = np.meshgrid(x_range, y_range)
Z = np.sin(2*np.pi*X) + 4*np.power(Y - 0.5, 2) #function height for the sake of an example
```

and then plot the thing with the standard:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
plt.title('Original function')

plt.show()
```

this results in a pretty plot of the function just as I expected.

However, I'd like to select random points in a known interval. For that I tried the alternative:

```
start_val, end_val = -1,1
N = 100
x_range = np.random.uniform(low=start_val, high=end_val, size=N)
y_range = np.random.uniform(low=start_val, high=end_val, size=N)
(X,Y) = np.meshgrid(x_range, y_range)
Z = np.sin(2*np.pi*X) + 4*np.power(Y - 0.5, 2) #function height for the sake of an example
```

Unfortunately, that results in non-sense:

[image]

instead of something nicer as the original with the evenly spaced points:

[image]

does someone know how to do the task (or a similar task) I am trying to do but being able to plot random points or include some randomness in a sensible way?

Comment: This sounds interesting, but I don't understand your main goal: `I wanted to select random points in a 2D plane and then plot a surface plot of how that would look like`. How would you get the height information for the surface from choosing random points in 2D? For example, if you randomly chose (4,4) in 2D, how do you get the third value in 3D (4,4,?)

Comment: I suggest sorting x_range and y_range before using them in meshgrid.

Comment: @rbierman if you have two matrices of their X and Y coordinates you can just compute what the function is. In your example, you do `np.sin(2*np.pi*X) + 4*np.power(Y - 0.5, 2)` wth X=4 and Y=4. As long as you have the coordinates organized so that ith X corresponds to ith Y, then you just compute Z with f(X[i],Y[i]).

Comment: @rbierman the goal is to plot the function with choosing points randomly rather than with the structure that they have to be evenly interleaved. Does that make sense? I am happy to clarify however I can.

Comment: @ᴡᴏʀᴅs I thought of sorting too, but sorting x and y separately might make that the indexes don't correspond to their correct pair value. In any case, I'm not sure how to sort those two things jointly such that that property is conserved. I suppose its not really possible...right?

Comment: There are no pairs to preserve. meshgrid will match every x value to every y value. The order is needed so that the plotting routine will know which points are neighbors, and will be able to draw polygons between them.

Comment: @ᴡᴏʀᴅs so the suggestion is to sort both x and y separately then? Right?

Comment: Yes, try that and see what happens. I don't have a place to test right now.

Comment: @ᴡᴏʀᴅs it seems like that worked. Why was that the solution? Maybe when you get time to write up the answer you can explain a bit and then I can upvote you and accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The x and y ranges used for meshgrid should not be in random order. This is because to draw a surface, it's not enough just to have a bunch of points in XYZ space: we also need to know which are to be connected with which. This is determined from the adjacency of values in the arrays.

Example: if x_range is [1, 2, 3] and y_range is [5, 9], then we know that the points (1,5), (2,5), (1,9), and (2,9) form the vertices of a rectangle to be included in the surface (with the corresponding Z-values, of course). If the x_range was instead [1, 3, 2], we would instead have a rectangle based on (1,5), (3,5), (1,9), and (3,9).

To have a graph of z=f(x,y), we need sorted x and y arrays, so that rectangles we get look like this:

[image: plot]

(For parametric graphs, with x,y,z being functions of parameters u,v, we won't necessarily have sorted x and y values; but u  and v probably will be, and their order will determine the order of x,y.)

Comment: sorry for the follow up but I suspect that sorting only works because I considered sampling the 2D plane uniformly and totally randomly (i.e. x and y coords are independent, so p(x,y) = p(x)p(y)). In this case sorting has no effect. But if the x,y plane was sample with a distribution that was special and cared about the joint values of x,y, would simply sorting still work?My intuition tells me that we might still need to sort (so that the plotting functions display correctly)but in a way to retain the corresponding x,y pairs? Or am I wrong? Otherwise we might display the wrong (rand) function.

Comment: If you were to sample, say, a normal distribution, then meshgrid(x,y) wouldn't work for you: it creates equally many points for each value in the x array.  The independence, p(x)p(y), is built into what it does. To model a distribution with x-y dependency, you would need a change of coordinates x = f(u,v), y=g(u,v), where f,g transform the uniform distribution of u,v into the desired distribution of x,y. Then you'd use (U,V)=np.meshgrid(u,v),  and  X = f(U,V),  Y=f(U, V). The sorted things here would be the parameters u and v.  This is what I referred to at the end of the answer.

Comment: the thing I find very counter-intuitive is why if I just select points from above on a 2D grid with some distribution (any I want). Why can't meshgrid just use something like the nearest neighbours and connect the surface according to neighbours. Sorting just seems like a hack rather than a solution to the real problem (I avoided referencing your parametric u,v suggestion because I don't understand it, my apologies, I wish I understood it though).